# Mysql: обновление PK у дублированных значений строк одним запросом

Tags: update, mysql

*Если бы я смог правильно сформулировать, может я бы и нашел уже решение в сети, но я тут.*
Есть в mysql некая таблица search с колонками pos(primary key, AI) и anketa(id анкеты).
Пример данных:

```
pos|anketa  
1|2  
2|7  
3|2  
4|4 и т.д.
```

Суть вопроса состоит в том, чтобы *одним запросом обновить значение pos у определенной анкеты на значение MAX(pos)+1*.

Если бы значение anketa было бы уникальным - вопросов нет:

```
UPDATE search 
SET pos=(SELECT * 
         FROM (SELECT MAX(pos)+1 
               FROM search) AS `tmp`
        ) 
WHERE anketa=7
```

Но если возьмем значение anketa 2 (см. пример данных), то mysql выдает ошибку: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY'

P.s.: циклами через PHP я и сам могу. Меня интересует, возможно ли решить сию проблему чисто через mysql.

Comment: Уточните ещё раз: вы точно хотите самостоятельно обновлять значение PRIMARY KEY? Точно-точно?

Comment: Да. За это расстреливают?) Просто для простоты организации таблицы и уменьшения объема данных решил пойти таким путем.

Comment: За это увольняют.

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае, если вы хотите воспользоваться чистым MySQL-решением, вам все-равно потребуется переменная, в данном случае переменная MySQL. Если допустить установку начального значения такой переменной, решение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
SET @var = 0;
UPDATE
  search
SET
  pos = (
    SELECT
      res + @var := @var + 1
    FROM
      (SELECT MAX(pos) + 1 AS res FROM search) AS tmp
    )
WHERE
  anketa = 2;
```

Благодаря переменной @var, которая будет обновляться на каждой итерации, вы сможете присвоить записям с одинаковым значением anketa разные значения поля pos, которые будут начинаться с максимально возможного.